# Redirect ruby warnings to a different stream than stderr

Tags: ruby, warnings, stderr

I have a requirement to check the error output of a ruby command and fail the task if there are any errors. However as warnings are also output to the error stream and I do not want to fail on warnings I am looking for options to handle this. I do not want to switch warnings off.Please advise.

Comment: You could just override `Kernel#warn` for this requirement only. e.g. `module Kernel; alias_method :old_warn, :warn; def warn(msg); #do what you want with the warning; end; end;`

Comment: Why not format the warnings differently from the errors so that they are easily distinguishable? Then you can filter using `grep` or similar. Warnings and errors _should_ be distinguishable in the first place, so hacking around this in Ruby seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Could you please add some code examples how do you plan to handle error output? Are you going to monitor log files or it will be STDOUT?

Comment: i was trying to avoid any text parsing on the error stream output.There isn't a particular code example.I am using rspec to run selenium tests and at times  even though the test run is a failure the error is quietly caught in the test but the parent task looks at both rspec exit code and the error stream to determine a failure. As warnings appear here , it not a reliable way to deduce an error. The tests need to handle exceptions well but the tests are not in my control at the moment.